# Assigning a property to itself

Tags: ios, swift

I don't understanding this error. Please check the code below:

```
class CardCarousel: UIView {
    var numberOfRatesLabel: UILabel

    var bestRates: BestRates! {
        didSet {
            numberOfRatesLabel.text = bestRates.title
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.numberOfRatesLabel = numberOfRatesLabel
        super.init(frame: frame)

        initComponents()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        initComponents()
    }

    private func initComponents() {
        numberOfRatesLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        self.addSubview(numberOfRatesLabel)
    }
}
```

I checked all the questions mentioning this error. I tried something but nothing better happened.

I found this error:

> Assigning a property to itself.

If I put `numberOfRatesLabel` in the parameter of the `init` method I have this error:

> Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

Comment: 'self.numberOfRatesLabel = numberOfRatesLabel'. You are assigning a property to itself, what don't you understand about it?

Comment: you are assigning a property to itself , it does not make sens.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    self.numberOfRatesLabel = numberOfRatesLabel // <- no local declaration of numberOfRatesLabel
    super.init(frame: frame)

    initComponents()
}
```

You just should implement something like this:

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect, numberOfRatesLabel: UILabel) {
    self.numberOfRatesLabel = numberOfRatesLabel
    self.init(frame: frame)

    initComponents()
}
```

That should do the trick. You don't have to override `init(frame: CGRect)`. But as you initiate the label in `initComponents()`you can go for this:

```
var numberOfRatesLabel: UILabel?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    initComponents()
}
```

All depends on your use cases.

Answer (score 1):

in the following line : 
`self.numberOfRatesLabel = numberOfRatesLabel`

You have no local declaration for `numberOfRatesLabel` so it's equal to 
`self.numberOfRatesLabel = self.numberOfRatesLabel`
As there is no reason do to that, `swift` prevents you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I in place the comments what I am feeling wrong about the initializer
I checked at my place now its working fine hope this will also work for you also.

please read comments carefully.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // this is what you are doing wrong because numberOfRatesLabel class member is not came in to existance without its instance got memory
        // you can comment this line if you want to assign a uilable to the numberOfRatesLabel from other class
        //self.numberOfRatesLabel = numberOfRatesLabel
        super.init(frame: frame)

        initComponents()
    }
    // and still you want to initilize with constructor then you should use convenience Initilizer
    convenience  init(frame: CGRect, num_ofRatLabel : UILabel) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        self.numberOfRatesLabel = num_ofRatLabel
    }
```